# How do I use libdb-4.2 in a FreeBSD 9.1 system?

Tags: c, freebsd, berkeley-db

I'm attempting to write a small program in C that will open and read from a Berkeley 4.2 hash DB on a FreeBSD 9.1 system for testing, but I can't get it to compile. This is the first time I've written anything in C and compiled from a command line so I'm probably missing one thing that'll get it working, I don't know.

After searching all over and looking at documentation and source code on github, this is what I've got so far:

```c
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <db.h>

int main()
{                                                                 
  DB * mydb;                                                                
  u_int32_t open_flags = DB_RDONLY;
  int ret;

  ret = db_create(&mydb, NULL, 0);
  if (ret != 0) {
    printf("Error creating DB structure!");
    return 1;
  }

  ret = mydb->open(mydb, NULL, "bsddb-py", NULL, DB_HASH, open_flags, 0);
  if (ret != 0) {
    printf("Error opening DB file!");
    return 2;
  }

  mydb->close(mydb, 0);
}
```

I compile with this:

```
cc -ldb-4.2 db_test.c
```

And get this:

```
db_test.c: In function 'main':
db_test.c:20: error: 'DB_RDONLY' undeclared (first use in this function)
db_test.c:20: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
db_test.c:20: error: for each function it appears in.)
db_test.c:29: error: 'DB' has no member named 'open'
db_test.c:35: error: too many arguments to function 'mydb->close'
```

Apparently the compiler is hung up on using Berkeley 1.85 (dbopen and such) and it won't budge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `#include <db.h>` will provide an interface to Berkeley 1.85 because that's what's installed by default on FreeBSD. We have Berkeley 4.2 installed via ports, and to avoid conflicts, the header that interfaces with 4.2 is put elsewhere - I was referencing the right library but not the right header.

So, I changed the include to:

```
#include <db42/db.h>
```

...and compiled with...

```
cc -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -ldb-4.2 db_test.c -o db_test
```

Running the above source with that modification produced no visible output, which means it worked!

As a newbie to it, BSD is weird.

Answer (score 0):

DB_RDONLY is contained in some header file that you are not #including. That should take care of all the line 20 errors.

Line 29: a DB struct apparently doesn't have a member named open. Recheck the struct/maybe you forgot to include the file that that struct is declared in.

35:  Seems like the function close doesn't take 2 arguments. Recheck this in the header file/make sure you included the header file.

Comment: All of [Oracle's docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/dbcreate.html) and the example code I looked at on github ([here](https://github.com/gburd/libdb/blob/master/examples/c/ex_env.c) and [here](https://github.com/gburd/libdb/blob/master/examples/c/ex_access.c)) include those above files and nothing more.

Comment: If your library is not installed to the default search path, then it should read #include "db.h" if its in your root directory (in the same directory as the file that includes it.  Otherwise, put the full path to the file such as #include "this/is/where/it/is/db.h"

Comment: The full path to the library I'm attempting to use is `/usr/local/lib/libdb-4.2.so`, and `cc` finds the library no problem when I specify it with `-ldb-4.2`. There is no actual `.h` file I'm aware of, but all of the examples I look at say to `#include <db.h>`.

Comment: it should read -llibdb-4.2 i  believe.  Try that out.  Sorry, didn't know you were using a shared library.  The lib might not be necessary though.  Also, you have to add /usr/local/lib/ to your ld_library path so that it searches there for the .so files.  That might be the issue.

Comment: No, the `-l` switches automatically know to look for files beginning with "lib". I receive no error about the library not being found, so I'm certain that switch is correct.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Try this gcc myprogram.c -ldb-4.2 -L /usr/local/lib

Comment: No, that didn't do it. But all of this gave me a nudge in the right direction and I figured it out.